# Centos iptables blocks after reboot

Tags: iptables, centos-5

I have a Centos5 installation with kvm on my server. I am using nat portforwarding to ssh my virtual machines. I have several iptables rules and saved then in /etc/sysconfig/iptables.

After reboot, I see all these rules when I type `service iptables status` but I am getting a connection refused error. After typing `service iptables restart` everything works. I don't understand, why do I need to restart iptables again? Doesn't it restart on reboot?

Comment: Check `/etc/network/interfaces` for pre-up and post-up commands, there could be some other iptables rules. Same thing with `/etc/rc.local`.

Comment: It depends on network interface somehow. If i restart network when everything works, it doesn't work again. I mean iptables must be started after network, otherwise it doesn't work. How can i find if network script adds some other rules? i can't find anything in eth script.